# Generar query para versionamiento automático sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2012

En mi tabla cotización tengo un campo llamado versión que es de tipo decimal(5.1) y se muestra de la siguiente manera.

1.0

1.1

1.2

1.3

hay una manera que esto se pueda generar la versión automáticamente. al momento de ingresar un registro a la tabla.

Comment: Por defecto lo que pides yo diría que no es posible. Lo único que se me ocurre es usar un procedimiento almacenado que calcule ese numero, y añadir un `trigger` contra esta tabla que llame a dicho procedimiento.

Comment: @Marco no es correcto pero puedes hacer una llave primaria string y puedes hacer el autoincrement manual